# No Value specified for parameter 2

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I am getting this error when trying to run my Spring boot.
java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 2
My code is this:

```
    public UserTemp findHistoryByID(Integer Patient_Number) {
    String sql = "select Col1\n" +
            "from (\n" +
            "    select Past_Diagnoses_1 as Col1\n" +
            "    from patienthistory\n" +
            "    where Patient_Number = ?\n" +
            "    union\n" +
            "    select Past_Diagnoses_2 as Col1\n" +
            "    from patienthistory" +
            "    where Patient_Number = ?" +
            "    ) as T;";

        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{Patient_Number}, (rs, rowNum) ->
            new UserTemp(
                    rs.getString("Col1")

            ));
}
```

Comment: You have 2 placeholder (`?`) in your query but you only pass one argument. A human can see that both are the same, but how should the code know? Pass `Patient_Number` twice

Comment: I am now getting the error IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 2

Comment: You want only one result, but your query returns two or more.

Comment: You're doing a `UNION` - youre getting back `0-2` rows. The method `queryForObject` is designed for queries returning `0-1` rows.

Comment: How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the comments, you are having 2 placeholders in the SQL query. So you have to pass `patient_number` 2 times.

Coming to your second question, it depends on your requirement.

1. If you need a single result, you need to fix it on the DB side as it's a data issue or the query used is not proper.
2. If more than one result is allowed, you can use `jdbcTemplate.queryForList()` instead of `jdbcTemplate.queryForObject()`. And change the return type of `findHistoryByID()` to List<Map<String,Object>> and all callers of this function.

**Note:** Here key for each Map in List is column names returned from DB.

More information on `jdbcTemplate.queryForList()` is in [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html)